# How to override MVC "Add Controller"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a visual studio extension to create a new wizard or override the current "Add Controller".

[image: Add Controller Wizzard]

I Have the extension made and everything set up, but i cant seem to use any code generators in .net framework, i tried the System.Web.Razor.Generator and the Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.

Does anyone done this before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This link contains all what you need(may be),
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should let you add your own template to the wizard so you can easily add replicated templates.

You can also add or edit views as well

> So in this article we have seen how to modify the existing code or
>   adding our own custom code generation for scaffolding column for
>   generating a Controller class and view in ASP.Net MVC3 using T4 Code
>   Generation.

[image]

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b19d5a/modifying-or-adding-the-default-code-generationscaffolding/

Comment: I have my templates created, i wanted to literally edit the wizzard